# How do I git deploy an .fsproj based f# project to azure?

Tags: asp.net, git, azure, f#, kudu

I have an ASP.NET core application that I've been auto-deploying to an azure app service on commit to a git repo. It worked fine as a project.json type project.

I've converted my project.json to myproject.fsproj and it builds and runs locally. On comitting the .fsproj to git, the deployment was triggered, but it failed with the activity log containing one line: 'D:\home\site\repository\myproject.fsproj' is not a deployable project.

I guess it's an issue with the default kudu deployment script? Does anyone know how to sort this out, or do I need to submit an issue/RFC to the kudu guys?

*UPDATE*

I generated the original .fsproj using: 
`dotnet new mvc --language f# --framework netcoreapp1.0`

I've since made changes to it, so I will try to do a minimal case later tonight.

Comment: VS 2017rc? or 2015? The point being is that it might possibly be difference in how this is built. Which again is dependent on a plethora of configurations and possibly build agents.

Comment: Neither. The .fsproj I generated by using dotnet new. I'll update the question.

Comment: Msbuild is the one used I think for building. Try to do same locally. Also: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/08/26/running-a-pure-f-web-api-on-azure-web-sites/

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the default deployment in azure wouldn't deal with this.

Following the answer on [Kudu Deployment Script for ASP.NET Core 1.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698263/kudu-deployment-script-for-asp-net-core-1-0), I generated a custom deployment script using:

`npm install -g kuduscript`

`kuduscript -y --aspNetCore myproject.fsproj`

Added the resulting deploy.cmd along with a .deployment:

`[config]
command = deploy.cmd`

A deployment triggered by a push to git works as expected now.

Comment: Yeah... but you have the same problem now and you've ended up at your own answer :|